# One timer object that all timers in the TextView are updated

Tags: java, android, timer

My application should show several timers and start them at the same time.

The problem is that these don't run in sync. You can see this on the GIF, you can see that they lose synchronicity.
After a certain time you can see that a timer is updated faster than the others. First timer 1 is displayed, followed by timer 2 with a delay and then again with a certain delay timer 3.

I want to create multiple timers and each timer has a different duration.
I want to display these timers in a TextView.  I initialize this in an ArrayList in the `MainActivity`. These are then added in a `ReyclerView` so that they are also displayed. To start, I go through a for loop and execute the `startTimer()` method for each individual object. Unfortunately, the times are not correct for every timer. That means one timer is faster, the second is slower and so on. So each timer starts at different times or the text changes at different times.

> Have only one timing item (e.g., ScheduledExecutorService) in a
> viewmodel, not 10 in an activity. While you may want to depict 10
> times, in the UI, you only need one timing item to tell you when a
> second has elapsed. Have the viewmodel emit details of the time values
> that should be rendered in the UI. Have the UI simply display those
> time values

This text on top was an answer. How could I build this in so that I only have one timer element and it controls the times? How can I let these timers run synchronously?
Each timer should be updated and displayed at the same time.
I look forward to an answer, thank you in advance for your support!

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ModelTimer.MyCallback {


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Button button_start;
private Dialog epicDialog;

public static ArrayList<ModelTimer> timerList;
public static TimerAdapter adapter;
public static Context context;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_timers);
    button_start = findViewById(R.id.button_start);

    timerList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        timerList.add(new Timer(i, 600000 * i))); //Each timer has a different time
    }

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    adapter = new TimerAdapter(this, timerList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    context = this;


    button_start.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        for (Timer timer: timerList) {
            timer.startTimer();


        });

        @Override
        public void updateMyText(int index, long time) {
            timerList.get(index-1).setTime(time);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }






    @Override
    public void updateMyText(int index, long time) {
        timerList.get(index-1).setTime(time);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**ModelTimer**

```
public class ModelTimer {


    public interface MyCallback {
        public void updateMyText(int index, long time);
    }

    private int index;
    private long time;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long startTime;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private String timeLeftFormatted;
    private MyCallback myCallback = null;


    public ModelTimer(int index, long startTimeMilliseconds, MyCallback callback) {
        this.index = index;
        this.time = startTimeMilliseconds;
        mTimeLeftInMillis = startTimeMilliseconds;
        startTime = startTimeMilliseconds;
        this.myCallback = callback;
    }


    public void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mTimeLeftInMillis = startTime;
        timeLeftFormatted = formattedTime(startTime);
        changeText(index-1);
    }

    public void updateCountDownText() {
       //System.out.println("ID: " + getIndex() + " " + mTimeLeftInMillis);
        if(myCallback != null) {
            myCallback.updateMyText(getIndex(), mTimeLeftInMillis);
        }

    }


    private void changeText(int element) {

        String[] data = timeLeftFormatted.split(":");
        int hours  = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

        int timeSeconds = seconds + 60 * minutes + 3600 * hours;
        long milliseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(timeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        MainActivity.countdownList.get(element).setTime(milliseconds);
        MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public static long getMilliseconds(String time) {
        String[] data = time.split(":");
        int hours  = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

        int timeSeconds = seconds + 60 * minutes + 3600 * hours;
        return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(timeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }



    public static String formattedTime(long time) {
        int milliToSec = (int) (time / 1000);
        int hours = milliToSec / 3600;
        int minutes = (milliToSec / 60) % 60;
        int seconds = milliToSec % 60;
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public long getTime() { return this.time; }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

**TimerAdapter**

```
public class TimerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelTimer> list;
    static String indexCountdown;


    TimerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelTimer> list) {
        mContext = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_countdowns, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelTimer timerItemList = list.get(position);
        TextView index = holder.countdown_index;
        TextView time = holder.countdown_time;
        CardView layout = holder.layout_countdowns;

        index.setText(timerItemList .getIndex() +"");
        time.setText(ModelTimer.formattedTime(timerItemList .getTime()));

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView countdown_index, countdown_time;
        private CardView layout_countdowns;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            countdown_index = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coutdown_index);
            countdown_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countdown_time);
            layout_countdowns = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_countdown);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with CountDownTimer if you want. It would look like this:

```
public class TimerHelper {

    public interface UpdateCallback {

        /**
         * @return true if want to be updated again false otherwise
         */
        boolean secondPassedCallback();
    }

    private ArrayList<UpdateCallback> callbacksList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param maxTime maximum of all timers
     */
    public void start(int maxTime) {

        CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(maxTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                ArrayList<UpdateCallback> itemsToRemove=new ArrayList<>();

                for (UpdateCallback updateCallback : callbacksList) {
                    boolean wantToBeUpdated = updateCallback.secondPassedCallback(); // remove timers that reached 0
                    if (!wantToBeUpdated) {
                        itemsToRemove.add(updateCallback);
                    }
                }
                callbacksList.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }


    public boolean addCallback(UpdateCallback callback) {
        return callbacksList.add(callback);
    }

    public boolean removeCallback(UpdateCallback callback) {
        return callbacksList.remove(callback);
    }

}
```

With this just make your ModelTimer implement this callback and do the UI update there. Finally in activity change button_start OnClickListener to:

```
    button_start.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        TimerHelper t = new TimerHelper();
        for (ModelTimer timer : timerList) {
            t.addCallback(timer);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can in your `ReyclerView ViewHolder` instead of inside in `ModelTimer`

```
chronometer.setBase(new Date().getTime());
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
         long t = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
         cArg.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", t));
    }
 });
 chronometer.start();
```